# How to update a document under a condition, using one query only

Tags: mongoose, mongodb-query

Let's suppose we have a collection with documents like this:

```
{
    status: 'running',
    progress: {
        total: 50,
        completed: 40,
        error: 10
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to update the field "status" to "done", only **if (total = completed + error)**.

I have lots of threads updating the completed and error fields, and they must update the status if the progress is finished too.

But I want to do it in just one query, not making 2 queries. If I do it with 2 queries I can have sync problems (one thread reads the document, and a second one updates it before the first one updates... so some information is lost).

I know I can do this with a two-steps commit queries (using the document version). But I wondered if there is a one-query solution for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been reading the mongodb docs and found that in v3.6 they added the $expr operator, that allows this query.

In my case, the query I needed is:

```
db.pruebas.findOneAndUpdate( { $and: [ {"status": "running"}, { $expr: { $eq: [ "$progress.total", { $add: ["$progress.completed", "$progress.error"] } ] } } ] }, {$set:{"status": "done"}})
```